# How to display a list of images based off of urls from firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, rendering

I'm attempting to display a list of images (kinda like youtube thumbnails) from a collection containing documents in my firestore.
The Function that returns all of the urls goes as follows:

```
async function ListImageData()
{
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", userUID, "images"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log( doc.id, " => ", doc.data().image)
  });
}
```

This returns a list of urls that you can use as such to get an image to display:

```
<img src={doc.data().image} />
```

I would like to display an image for each document (and hopefully in the future be able to limit it to around 25 documents displayed at the time, this is not critical at the moment though)

Thanks!

Comment: can you take a look at my answer ?

Comment: The code keeps throwing errors, its fine

Comment: Errors like what kind of errors can you elaborate those ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by just changing some part of your code like this. I think you are using React based on your img tag reference.
Modified code:

```
async function ListImageData() {
  const imageUrls = [];
  const q = query(collection(db, "users", userUID, "images"), limit(25));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    imageUrls.push(doc.data().image);
  });
  return imageUrls;
}
```

If you require all documents to be returned then just remove the `,limit(25)` from the query.

Then in React component you can render your images in many ways and I have provided one of them However I have not provided the loading state as it is will be fetched from cloud storage/firebase storage so also note on that:

**ImageGallery.js** :

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageGallery = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((imageUrl) => (
        <img src={imageUrl} alt="Gallery image" key={imageUrl} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ImageGallery;
```

And then to render this component use the following:

**App.js** :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const imageUrls = await ListImageData();
      setImages(imageUrls);
    }
   fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <ImageGallery images={images} />;
};
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution in a couple of different ways, but even with a fresh project, it pops the error: {Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.} I have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: @HelloToxicity Hi updated the code as your error

Comment: Sorry, your the goat, tweaked a few things and it works!